# Puma + Rackup + Sinatra: config file ignored when using rackup

Tags: ruby, sinatra, rubymine, puma, rackup

I am struggling with puma in context of Rubymine and Rackup.
I created a small app that is binding usig ssl and gets its parameter from /config/puma.rb or /config/puma/production.rb

That works fine if I start it with
puma or Puma -C /config/puma.rb or puma -E production

> ```
> puma starting in single mode...
> * Version 3.12.0 (ruby 2.4.5-p335), codename: Llamas in Pajamas
> * Min threads: 0, max threads: 16
> * Environment: development
> * Listening on ssl://127.0.0.1:9001?cert=./keys/s3l.cer&key=./keys/s3l.key&verify_mode=peer&ca=./keys/sso_ca.crt
> Use Ctrl-C to stop
> ```

Unfortunately RubyMine IDE for sinatra apps is using a hardcoded rackup command to start the server, in addition is providing commandline parameters for IP/Port and with this puma is not really reading its config file.

In console it is consistently ignoring config file:

> rackup -E production
>   Puma starting in single mode...
>   * Version 3.12.0 (ruby 2.4.5-p335), codename: Llamas in Pajamas
>   * Min threads: 0, max threads: 16
>   * Environment: production
>   * Listening on tcp://0.0.0.0:9292

=> wrong ip, port and no ssl!

- I tried to it with and without environment => not reading the ssl
  binding
- I tried to forward the -C parameter with -O C=[path] in    config.ru
  to puma command   => not reading
- I tried to avoid all this and do it in sinatra, but this is to late
  in "boot"

So how to I run a sinatra app with Rubymine by pressing a play button that triggers rackup? 
I need to execute the config file because there is my ssl binding defined... I need to use rackup because rubymine forces it. I need rubymine for debugging

At the end of it all my expectation would have been:
I or rubymine IDE call rackup, it reads his config.ru, it calls puma and puma is looking for its configfile depemding on -E
But puma is not looking for its file

**pumar.rb**

```
   cert= "./keys/s3l.cer"
   key = "./keys/s3l.key"
   ca=  "./keys/sso_ca.crt"
   verify_mode= "peer"
bind "ssl://127.0.0.1:9001?cert=#{cert}&key=#{key}&verify_mode=#{verify_mode}&ca=#{ca}"
```

**config.ru**

hash\ -s puma -O -C=./config/pumar.rb

require 'rubygems'

require './app'

run App

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Run/Debug configuration and add parameters to the rack configuration RubyMine executes (be sure to add it in the rack configuration, not Ruby): https://www.jetbrains.com/help/ruby/creating-and-editing-run-debug-configurations.html

Just add `-C puma.rb` to the parameters.